# Apexcharts time not matching JavaScript/Python

Tags: javascript, vue.js, apexcharts

In my Python

```
  2020-09-23T10:50:46.838023
```

In JavaScript

```
  2020-09-23T10:50:46.838023
```

In JavaScript apexcharts format

```
  2020-09-23T03:50:46.838023
```

why has it changed the hour from 10 to 03?

This my Vue code

```
chartOptions: {
              chart: {
                id: "chart" + key,
                type: obj.chart,
                zoom: {
                  enabled: false,
                },
              },
              tooltip: {
                x: {
                  format: 'dd/MMM HH:mm:ss',
                }
              },
              xaxis: {
                type: "datetime",
                categories: obj.time,
                labels: {
                  show: true
                }
              },
            },
          };
```

My `obj` is object used for `foreach` loop.

Comment: What timezone are you in? GMT+7 is my bet. So this apexcharts is showing GMT, everything else is showing your local timezone

Comment: I should change timezone in apexcharts  or something else ?

Comment: no idea what apexcharts is, sorry, I'm just telling you where the 7 hours difference is - the difference may be due to your code or apexcharts code, I don't know as you've shown no code, and apexcharts is not something I know

Answer (score 11, accepted):

If you want to display local time in ApexCharts, turn off the UTC flag on x-axis labels.

```js
xaxis: {
  labels: {
    datetimeUTC: false
  }
}
```